# Ubuntu 14.04 - after installation no bootloader, so Windows 7 starts

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation, uefi

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 for the first time.
There is also working Windows 7 on that PC.

After the installation from Ubuntu 14.04 with an USB-Stick I clicked on "restart" and the system told me to unplug the USB-Stick. Ok done.
But then the system started with Windows 7 and I had no choice nor chance to change the OS I wanted to start.

So my PC has no UEFI just an old BIOS and in the Ubuntu Wiki I can't find a way to change the Windows bootloader.
So what can I do to start Ubuntu??? :-(

Comment: What happens if you boot while holding the SHIFT key?

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens, you need to use a live ubuntu dvd on a dvd or a flash drive then install boot-repair on it and run it.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate hard drives in your machine, make sure to set the correct boot order in the BIOS.

It sounds like you didn't partition one hard drive, but instead your machine sees the Windows 7 disk and boots from it first.

---

When your PC reboots, hold TAB to see your "boot menu" shortcut key (ESC for my ASUS, F9 for my HP).

In the boot menu, try to boot from your Ubuntu drive.

If this works, you just need to go into setup and select the correct boot order for your disks. (D first, and then C).

(Note: The C and D labels wont be there, as that is a windows construct. The hard drives will have their own name)

Comment: Drive C is my Windows system on its own disk. And drive D is my second harddisk also used for windows backups. I partitioned drive D with 50% for Ubuntu.

Comment: Great, thanks for the followup, it's possible your BIOS is booting the wrong device. Check out my edited answer for more help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First go to **boot menu** (for hp its f9) and see if your ubuntu boot loader exist (GRUB)..
if it exist then go to **BIOS setup**. Go to **system configuration**. In system configuration go to **OS boot manager** which is under the heading UEFI boot order.
There you will find your boot loader's (i.e., windows boot loader and GRUB). There change the order by pressing F5 or F6 (remember these keys are for my hp laptop and might be different for your laptop/PC, but dont worry as they will specify the keys below your BIOS setup.) then click on save and exit. This will reboot your system. After reboot you should be able to see your GRUB.

I hope this would solve your problem.